# Calling Lisp from Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lisp

How might you call a Lisp program from a Rails application?...  For example, allow the end user to enter a block of text in the Rails web app, have the text processed by the Lisp program and return results to the Rails app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another simple way is to have Lisp running a HTTP server and contact Lisp from the outside via HTTP requests.

Comment: I'm not sure that most people would consider that as simple as above, but perhaps for RoR people it might even be simpler...

Comment: In a web setting this is the usual service-oriented architecture. There are lots of web servers for Lisp and exchanging data via HTTP requests is easy. All you need to do is let the Lisp server respond to a POST request.

Answer (score 11):

There are a couple ways that come to mind:

1. Execute the lisp program with [Process](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html). Communicate with the Lisp program via standard in, and have the Lisp program output its result over stdout.
2. Do the same thing as above, but communicate via [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) instead. Have your Ruby code write data *into* a named pipe, then have the Lisp program read from that pipe, and write data *out* over another named pipe which you then read with your Ruby app. The Lisp program can either run in the background as a daemon that checks for data on its incoming pipe, or you can fire it up as-needed using Ruby's command-line utilities (as above).
3. Find a Ruby-Lisp bridge. I have no experience with such a bridge (nor do I know off-hand if one even exists) and I think the above 2 mechanisms are easier, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 4):

[CL-JSON](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/) supports [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC).  It's very easy to set up with a web server such as [Hunchentoot](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/) to have a Lisp-based web service that anything that speaks JSON-RPC (e.g. [this](http://json-rpc.rubyforge.org/)) can use.

Comment: I'd like to learn more about this approach. Could you tell/point me how to set it up? And what it allows you to do, that's better than HTTP POST requests?

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on how often it's going to happen.

- If it's once in a blue moon, then just run a backquote command that starts the lisp interpreter, or popen it and write to it.
- If it happens all the time, you will need to have Lisp already running, so the question then is how to communicate. Any of the interprocessor mechanisms will work, but I would suggest a TCP socket for development, testing, and production flexibility.
- If it happens a million times a day, but a toy Lisp would be good enough, it is a simple matter to implement Lisp with Ruby classes. This was done as chapter 8 of *Practical Ruby Projects*.